# How to add static text inside a Laravel form text input?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I want to add static text within a laravel form text input.

I created a custom slug field and I want the domain to show left aligned on the input. How would I do this?

```
{{ Form::label('slug', 'URL:') }}
{{ Form::text('slug', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31802640/how-to-add-static-text-to-an-input-box-in-bootstrap) created by TheLuminor is exactly what I want but I cannot figure out how to do that with the Laravel form builder. I have also skimmed the [Forms/HTML section of the Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html) and failed to find anything relating to my problem.

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using? Form:: is not part of Laravel since Laravel 4.2. You may be using the [Laravel Collective package](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.0/html)

Comment: The question you note will work perfectly.  Just treat the `Form::` elements exactly as he does with the normal `<form>` elements, add the divs and the spans around them in the same way.  Laravel collective forms is just a nice way to save a huge amount of time.  Under the hood it is just normal html forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
{{ Form::label('slug', 'URL:') }}

<div class="input-group">
    {{ Form::text('slug', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
    <div class="input-group-append"><span class="input-group-text">@gmail.com</span></div>
</div>
```