# Font Awesome's unicode not working in fixed placeholder

Tags: css, unicode, font-awesome

I followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22941903/placing-static-text-at-the-end-of-an-input-field-using-html) to have a placeholder at the end of the input which doesn't disappear when filling it (cf Airbnb's login modal for example).

However, I used Font Awesome's unicode and added a font family attribute but it doesn't work:

```
.email-container {
   width:100%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.email-container:after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    color:#999999;
    top: 10px;
    content: '&#xf0e0;';
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

I have `&#xf0e0;` at the end of the line
I'm trying to add the fa-envelope icon.
Where did I miss something ?

Comment: Which icon you trying to use ?

Comment: Edited it: I want the fa-envelope icon. It does exist: 
 fa-envelope [&#xf0e0;]
Are brackets necessary ? I've previously used Font Awesome's unicodes without it and it worked.
https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have incorrect unicode charater notation.
For CSS you should replace `&#x` with simple backslash `\`. Also `;` at the end should be removed.

Here's the change you should do:

> &#x**f0e0**; => \**f0e0**

Try this:

```
.email-container:after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    color:#999999;
    top: 10px;
    content: '\f0e0'; // <-- changed line
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

Comment: Worked, thanks ! However: when should I use this notation and not the one provided in their cheat sheet ? I've used the '&#xf0e0;' notation before and it worked fine.

Comment: `&#x0000;` is a HTML entity. So you can use it when you place this char directly in HTML. More about HTML entities: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
content: " ("&#xf0e0")";
```